# How to fix a clanking rear wheel/flywheel

Tags: freewheel, noise

On my single speed--a POS Bikes Direct bike--the rear wheel makes a clunking noise every time I pedal. I think it is coming from the freewheel and it's basically a CLINK! CLONK! noise that is driving me nuts.

I should mention that the seat stay on the left side of the bike is slightly longer than on the right. Therefore the back is asymmetrical. The tire rides perfectly in the center of the rear dropouts and between the chain stays. However, the tire is a right aligned to the right seat stay.

Here is a visual I sent to Bikes Direct to try to get them to fix it:
[image] 
And [here are pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sy4nj.jpg) of the bike from various angles.

Comment: Bicycles don't have flywheels. Put pictures of your actual bike.

Comment: Sorry about that @Batman. Autocorrect made that assumption on my behalf. I have since edited it. I have also added pictures of the actual bike to this album: http://imgur.com/a/9s0Pw

Comment: I'm not seeing your claim for the circled part being bent (that arch seems to be by design) -- it looks like the wheel might not be centered in the forkends (which you can remove the wheel and center it) and the brake caliper may not be mounted straight (undo the mounting bolt, tilt it to be right and then tighten the bolt). But its hard to tell since the pictures are at sorta a weird angle.

Comment: Hi @Batman - The pictures don't really do it justice. The wheel is centered on the fork ends, and, once you center the wheel between the chainstays, it's always closer to the right seat stay. This is why the brake is angled to the right. If I flip the wheel to the fixie side, the wheel still stays on the right side of the seat stay, therefore the wheel is symmetrical. I'm not sure that re-taking the photos will help as capturing this on a black frame makes it a hell of a bit more difficult.

Comment: Does it make the noise only when pedaling?  Only when not pedaling?  If it makes the noise while pedaling, does it sync with the pedals, or the wheel?

Comment: As I mentioned in my post, clunking noise happens every time I pedal. Nothing happens when I pedal backwards, or coast. Sometimes, when I go over a bump in the road, the noise will subside for a few cranks and then come back to haunt me.

Comment: From your previous comments I gather that the rear wheel is dual single/fixie wheel, right? Does your bike make the clunking noise when the back wheel is flipped to fixie side?

Comment: That's correct @OttoK. When I flip it, the noise goes away, so it leads me to believe that the freewheel is the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

From the comments above, it seems that it really is a free wheel that is making the noise.

Apparently cheap free wheels can be like that. Lubing them can help. This discussion has some extra info: http://forums.roadbikereview.com/fixed-single-speed/fix-shimano-freewheel-clunking-noises-150432.html

TL;DR version: Get some gear oil or grease gun and apply liberally.